# How to identify phages from Phaster in PhageDB

Tags: genome-sequencing

I am running searches for genes using **Phaster** {[PHASTER (PHAge Search Tool Enhanced Release) is a significant upgrade to the popular PHAST web server for the rapid identification and annotation of prophage sequences within bacterial genomes and plasmids.](https://phaster.ca/)   } and would like to look up the phages that have them on **PhageDB** [The Actinobacteriophage Database](https://phagesdb.org/about/) to learn more about their distribution. The blast search returns a lot of information about the phages and I am unsure what part of the sequence it gives for phages would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is Phaster? Can you please provide a brief description about the program, and ideally a link that we can visit to get more information? Also... this question doesn't really have a question in it. Could you please clarify what more precisely what you are struggling with?

Comment: I am not sure is a good idea to look for result on PHAGEDB , its full name list https://phagesdb.org/data/?set=all&type=simple ,  is probably smaller the the hits out of PHASTER

Comment: unless I am getting it wrong and you are asking to use https://phagesdb.org/blast/ local blast to search for your sequence inside PHAGEDB ?

Comment: mmmmmh  the phages on PHAGEDB that are not deposited at NCBI are the only one you should look/screen for , but still I am not getting your question PHASTER is used to track leftover presence of phage in plasmid and genomes , PHAGEDB is a repo (kind of non official for actionobacteria phages) or am I wrong ?